# Replace array in nested object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have spent a good part of the day trying to replace arrays of an existing nested object but I can't figure out how to do it. This is my original object:

```
{
  "id": "a8df1653-238a-4f23-fe42-345c5d928b34",
  "webSections": {
    "id": "x58654a9-283b-4fa6-8466-3f7534783f8",
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "92d7e428-4a5b-4f7e-bc7d-b761ca018922",
        "title": "Websites",
        "questions": [
          { 
            id: 'dee6e3a6-f207-f3db-921e-32a0b745557', 
            text: 'Website questions', 
            items: Array(11)
         }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "79e42d88-7dd0-4f70-b6b4-dea4b4a64ef3",
        "title": "Blogs",
        "questions": [
          ...
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "439ded88-d7ed0-de70-b6b4-dea4b4a64e840",
        "title": "App questions",
        "questions": [
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like replace the question arrays in the original object or in a copy of it.

```
const newMenu = [
{id: '34bb96c7-1eda-4f10-8acf-e6486296f4dd', text: 'Website questions', items: Array(24)},
{id: '520c2d3f-6117-4f6a-904f-2477e3347472', text: 'Blog questions', item: Array(7)},
{id: '302b658a-9d8c-4f53-80f6-3f2275bfble', title: 'App questions', items: Array(14)}
]
```

I am trying to do this by its index but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
 webSections.sections.forEach((item, index) => {
   return webSections.sections[index].questions, newMenu[index]);
 }
```

Does anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned from the callback passed to `forEach` will not be used anywhere.

If you want to avoid mutating the original object and update questions, you can use `Array.prototype.map` and object spread syntax.

```
const object = {
  "id": "a8df1653-238a-4f23-fe42-345c5d928b34",
  "webSections": {
    "id": "x58654a9-283b-4fa6-8466-3f7534783f8",
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "92d7e428-4a5b-4f7e-bc7d-b761ca018922",
        "title": "Websites",
        "questions": [
          { 
            id: 'dee6e3a6-f207-f3db-921e-32a0b745557', 
            ...

const updatedObject = {
 ...object,
 webSections: {
  ...object.webSections,
  sections: object.webSections.sections.map((section, index) => ({...section, questions: newMenu[index]}))
 }
}
```

If you just want to mutate the original object

```
object.webSections.sections.forEach((_, index) => {
 section.questions = newMenu[index]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const newSections = myObj.webSections.sections.map((obj, index) => {
        const newQuestions = newItems[index];
        return {
            ...obj,
            questions: [newQuestions],
        };
    });

    console.log(newSections);
```

MyObj is the main object.
This shall produce the new sections array you can combine it with your main object I suppose...

@Ramesh Reddy has the most thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you don't care about mutation is:

```js
myObject.webSections.sections.forEach((section, index) => {
  section.questions = newMenu[index].items;
})
```

You have used your 'forEach' with wrong syntax. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on how it's used.